# Hiding a context actionbar menu without fading

Tags: android, android-actionbar, contextmenu

I'm creating a context `ActionBar` menu and trying to hide it when the user taps the back button. But the menu is fading and the primary `ActionBar` is totally visible while it's fading out, it's slides up only after it faded out. Please watch this very short video: https://vimeo.com/315657854

Hiding the context actionbar menu and displaying the primary actionar

```
public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        actionMode = null;
        ActionBar myActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        myActionBar.show();
    }
```

How to immediately hide the context actionbar menu without fading?

Answer (score 0):

```
getSupportActionBar().setShowHideAnimationEnabled(false);
```

i think this is what u are looking for

Comment: ActionBar.setShowHideAnimationEnabled can only be called from within the same library group. I tried to place it inside "setOnItemLongClickListener" instead of "getSupportActionBar()" and in "onDestroyActionMode" and got the same error

Comment: Why do you think that? Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it